# Calculate the sum of observation values with conditions 2.0

Tags: r

The given data is:

```
farmer<-c("F1","F2","F3","F4","F5","F6")
animal<-c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8")
time<-c("T1","T2","T3","T4","T5")
disease<-c("ww","ee","dd","ss","kk","ll","xx","oo","hh")
sample(farmer,size=100,replace = TRUE)

df<-data.frame(farmer=sample(farmer,size=100,replace = TRUE),
               animal=sample(animal,size=100,replace = TRUE),
               time=sample(time,size=100,replace = TRUE),
               disease=sample(disease,size=100,replace = TRUE))
head(df)
```

[image]

Question: Number of farmers who have the same disease for specific animal and at specific time?

Output should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Martini. Could you perhaps show us what you have tried yourself and why it didn't work? SO is not a free code-writing / homework service, so you need to show evidence that you have put the effort in to solve the problem yourself, otherwise your question is at risk of closure.

Comment: What's the meaning of "2.0" in your title? Is it just copy/pasted from an assignment??

Comment: Hello@gregor thomas, 2.0 is actually the secondly edition of the question which I have previously asked. The first edition is not precise.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

dt <- setDT(df)

dt[, .(NumberOfFarmers = .N), by = .(animal, time, disease)]
```

I guess this should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this is not the right answer which I expect. As I'v mentiened on my question, it should be the same like the table I'v listed.

Comment: Then you should explain first how the columns potatoes, rape, soya and sunflower emerge.

Comment: No, that is only a simple structure which I used in order to explain how the result should be look like. The parametern in the table such as potatoes etc should not be considered about. And also, I have added red colour to replace the old parametern. Thanks.